# TemplateRef requires type argument

Tags: angular

Component HTML:

```
<ng-template #content/> </ng-template>
```

Component TS:

```
@ViewChild('content')
public content: TemplateRef;
```

Visual Studio message:

```
[ts] Generic type 'TemplateRef<C>' requires 1 type argument(s)
```

Am I supposed to just make it `TemplateRef<any>` ?
Code samples never seem to specify the generics though.
**Is this new ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `TempalteRef<any>` and in almost all use cases you'll be fine.

But if you want more information, you can read [this blog post](https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/10/01/angular-template-ref-dynamic-scoping-custom-templates/) *(specifically the "Dynamic Scoping in Angular"
 section)* by [Minko Gechev](https://github.com/mgechev).

Comment: This answeer needs to be picked @bvdb, nonetheless it lacks explanation and just points out to an article.

Comment: But we can't accept any or should we? There must be some type.

Answer (score 19):

In Angular Material 2 they used

```
TemplateRef<any>
```

everywhere 
https://github.com/angular/material2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=templateref&type=

I haven't seen anything where this type parameter would be relevant.

Comment: That doesn't explain though, why does the generic exits in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to use Angular best practices and don't use "`any`" as a type for the `TemplateRef<C>` when passing a reference to a HTML element you can use the generic interface type for html elements: `Element`

Component TS:

```
public content: TemplateRef<Element>;
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on Nexaddo post, I will elaborate here.
Given a component:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-modal',
      templateUrl: './my.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
    })
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
      data = "oldData";
      @ViewChild() template0:TemplateRef<any>;
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
    }
```

TempalteRef is a template reference as its name implies. `@ViewChild()` is just there to say "the template is in my view", you could use `@ContentChild()` or `@Input()` if you passed the template from the call to MyComponent.

When you summon it in your component template (*./my.component.html* here), in most cases you would do so :

```html
    <ng-template #template0>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        <p>{{data}}</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template0">
        
    </ng-container>
```

Here, the call to *template0* will interpolate *data* from the component context, because all templates inside it share the same context. But you could specify **another context** like so:

```html
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template0;context=newCtx">
        
    </ng-container>
```

From:

```js
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
      data = "oldData";
      newCtx = {data = "newData"};
      ...
    }
```

Like so, the "newData" will be interpolated instead of "oldData".

Now, you do realize *newCtx* has `any` as a type, and that's where `TemplateRef<any>` comes from. In most cases you might be fine with it, but for the sake of reusability or just for compiler check, you could precise which class this context should be: `TemplateRef<CustomContextClass>`, and you'd have to declare your context like so : `newCtx:CustomContextClass` (or any child class of CustomContextClass naturally).

src: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/ and https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/10/01/angular-template-ref-dynamic-scoping-custom-templates/